# Base64Decode: How to get the data

Tags: c++, crypto++

This seems like it would be an easy question, but crypto++ seems to be designed in a funky, "as obtuse as possible" sorta way, so I'm wondering...

How can I get the binary data out of the CryptoPP::Base64Decode object? Assuming I don't want to write it to a file, or encode it some other way, how do I just get at the actual binary data?

Edit: figured it out; not sure how to close/delete it, anyone? What's the appropriate thing for me to do here now?

Comment: Can you give us more detail on what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, figured it out. For reference, I wanted to get the MaxRetrievable and Get methods of the BufferedTransformation subclass.

Answer (score 0):

> This seems like it would be an easy question, but crypto++ seems to be
>   designed in a funky, "as obtuse as possible" sorta way, so I'm wondering...

Its not an easy question if you are not familiar with the Crypto++ design. There's actually two designs at work.

First is a classical Update/Final. Its implemented in Crypto++ with `Put` and `Get` and friends.

The second is a pipleline design. That's where data flows from source to sink, and you'll see it as, for example:

```
FileSource fs( "Hello World", true /*pumpAll*/
    new HexEncoder( e,
        new FileSink( "encoded.txt" )     
); // FileSource
```

The pipeline is equivalent to Unix commands:

```
echo "Hello World" | base64 >> encoded.txt
```

The pipeline generalizes to:

```
Source -> Filter -> Filter -> ... -> Filter -> Sink
```

Internally, Source will call `Put` on the first filter; the first filter will transform the data and call `Put` on the second filter, and so on. The last filter will call `Put` on the Sink. More correctly, the Source and Filters will call `Put2`, but that's an implementation detail.

If there is no Sink:

```
Source -> Filter -> NULL
```

then the Filter will internally buffer the transformed data. You can use `Get`, `GetWord16`, `GetWord32`, `MaxRetrievable`, `AnyRetrievable`, etc to extract data from the filter or sink.

`Put`, `Get`, `MaxRetrievable` and friends are part of the `BufferedTransformation` interface, and that's an interface that all filters and sinks implement (there's really no need for a source to implement it). If a class does not provide `Put`, `Get` and friends, then its not a filter or sink. Documentation for the class is located at [BufferedTransformation Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_buffered_transformation.html).

There's a lot more to it, including blocking and pumping data in blocks, but its not really needed for a Base64 filter or object. The `pumpAll` in the above example means to push all data at once.